what does the authority field in Raydium poolKeys type represent
In this type CpmmKeys when fetching poolKeys from Raydium, what does the authority field represent.
It isn't the liquidity pool creator's public key and I'd love to know what it represents.
The field in question -> https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2/blob/78d0e5c85b0f7f40b2db957976c6071763ca0ce8/src/api/type.ts#L322
On devnet, here is the authority for this pool DgXXHQNPy3nZbsNDNEVDiBHvA5EiYS2Jjki71LyMg5SZ I created, -> https://explorer.solana.com/address/7rQ1QFNosMkUCuh7Z7fPbTHvh73b68sQYdirycEzJVuw?cluster=devnet

In my opinion, the authority field in Raydium's CpmmKeys type represents the program-derived address (PDA) that acts as the manager of the liquidity pool, handling actions like deposits, withdrawals, and fee collection.

on devnet this is the address in question, https://explorer.solana.com/address/7rQ1QFNosMkUCuh7Z7fPbTHvh73b68sQYdirycEzJVuw?cluster=devnet
